# spring hello world MVC application is not responding

Tags: spring-mvc

I created a simple maven based spring Helloworld MVC application using jdk 1.7, eclipse kepler and tomcat 7 . At the time of deploying the app it is not showing any errors and it is displaying only welcome file. When I am trying to access the resource it is not responding to the request and simply displaying requested resource not found. I struck ed here some one please help me in this.
regards,
Rama krishna.

Comment: Post your code, such that we can help you

Comment: Post codes of web.xml,Spring config files and Controller code.